# How to properly pass self in stacked decortors on class methods in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, decorator, chain

First, I would like to have a class method, that is concerened only with manipulating a dataframe column. So that i can really focus on the manipulation itself rather than the background stuff. This background stuff is actually applying this simple function over specified columns (e.g. all numeric ones, stated explicitly by their column name)
To seperate this from the nasty bits, i tryed using decorators and actually succeded.

However the difficulty arose as i wanted to use a second decorator that is in fact a plotting method for each of those manipulated columns to keep track on the manipulations.

The code that you find below is a working version and simplified:
plotter is merely printing each columns name rather than actually plotting it

Note the commented self, that allows this code to work propperly. I dont understand why.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class test_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

    def plotter(fn):
        def printer(self, **kwargs):
            print('printer call')
            for col in kwargs['column']:
                print(col)
            return fn(self, **kwargs) # this self actually allows to applyer to referencne self, otherwise: applyer positional argument missing

        return printer

    def wrapapply(fn):
        def applyer(self, **kwargs):
            print('applyer call')
            fnkwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k != 'column'}  # clean up the decorators arguments
            self.df[kwargs['column']] = pd.DataFrame.apply(self.df[kwargs['column']], func=fn, axis=0, **fnkwargs)

        return applyer

    @plotter
    @wrapapply
    def norm(column):
        return (column - np.mean(column)) / np.std(column)


if __name__ == '__main__':


    a = test_class()
    a.norm(column=['A', 'B'])
    a.norm(column=['D'])

    print(a.df)
```

The result i expect is

1. a silent inplace manipulation of all columns A, B, D in the
   Dataframe,
2. each of the columnames of a call must be printed by a seperate
   decorator function (as in my application, this is in fact a plotting
   method)

Comment: Is this indented correctly? As written, `plotter`, `wrapapply`, and `norm` are methods on `test_class`

Comment: yes indeed. probably i should have excluded it from the class. This makes sense. Thank you! Does this already answer my question? I have never used decorators in the context of classes before - so the obvious way of excluding it from the class may already render the question of how to pass self in the decorator method obsolete - doesn't it?